# Can ZMQ publish and read in the same thread?

Tags: c++, zeromq

I've been trying to publish some data, using a **`ZMQ_PUB`** socket and then read it in the same thread, using **`ZMQ_SUB`**.
But it looks like it's dropping the data before read.
**Is there a way to do this using ZMQ?**

Comment: Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Yep, pub/sub is almost guaranteed to drop data. You need to read all of the ZMW documentation.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, there is a way to do this, using ZeroMQ

There are several details on PUB/SUB behaviour, one has to pay attention to meet, or suprises happen.

Check the Pieter HINTJENS' schematic, to start getting interested in details involved:

[image]

---

### The Best Next Step:

**An absolutely great perspective for doing this** and a good read for realistic designs with ZeroMQ is Pieter HINTJEN's book **"Code Connected, Vol.1"** ( [**may check** my posts on **ZeroMQ** to find the book's direct **pdf**-link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D) ).

Plus another good read comes from Martin SUSTRIK, the co-father of ZeroMQ, on [**low-level truths about the ZeroMQ implementation details** & scale-ability](http://nanomsg.org/documentation-zeromq.html)